DynamoDB Query empty response
I what to get items by query command with local index, but response is empty.
My code:
  const client = new DynamoDBClient({});
  const input = {
    TableName: "...",
    IndexName: "LITimestamp",
    KeyConditionExpression: 'PK = account#225873187286700#chat'
  }
  console.log(0, JSON.stringify(input));
  const command = new QueryCommand(input);
  let res;
  try {
    res = client.send(command);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(1, JSON.stringify(err));
  }
  console.log(2, JSON.stringify(res));



Can someone help me, I don't understand what is incorrect here

The send-command is async, so you'll have to await it:
try {
    res = await client.send(command);
} catch(err) {
    console.log(1, JSON.stringify(err));
}
console.log(2, JSON.stringify(res));

